# using wordpress with charset iso-8859-1 (latin1)

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I want t run a wordpress installation with a static export of the website, which i then want to upload to a clients server.

The Problem: the client server is still run with charset iso-8859-1 with no way to change it.

For now I export the files and manually change the html files afterwards.
Since the site is getting bigger I was wondering if there is a way to run wordpress with charset iso-8859-1.

I've already set my database to iso-8859-1 and changed the charset in the wp-config.php accordingly, but wordpress still seems to export to the database in utf-8 because I still get messed up characters. I also set the charset in the head tag of my Theme.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Note: the encoding of the server do no matter anymore. Just define in the meta header the charset (which should already be the case). Is it simple to convert charset in the database (before the dump, or just convert the dump, or when importing)? Note2: you are going backward. web is since several years UTF-8.

Comment: @Giacomo: Thank you, that's what I've been telling the client. But for now that's impossible to change for several reasons. I know i can convert encoding in the database but it's basically the same as to change it in the html with a script. I was wondering if there's a way to make wordpress write to the database in iso-8859. Because that's not happening for me

Comment: Probably wordpress writes transparently to the database, and so it doesn't need to care about converting. A system with latin1 will write into db in latin1, so no need to convert. So you do conversion only when porting from one machine to the other. I do not understand what do you mean for "the server do not support utf-8". This is just a convention of wordpress and the world. Servers should not care about user space encoding (and they do not care)

Comment: Sorry my bad. I clearly do not 100% understand the encoding thing and mixed up a few things. I export the website as static html for the client, who imports these files into their own custom-cms that runs completely in iso-8859 and therefore shows wrong characters when they get my files in utf-8. The problem on my side is, that wordpress natively runs in utf-8 and i cant get it to write to the database in iso-8859. When i check the database entries in phpadmin the assigned database encoding is correct, but when i look at the entries the characters are messed up.